# Most efficient way to store financial data (Python)

Tags: python, database, csv, panel

The data exists out of Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume and it's currently stored in a .csv file. It's currently updating every minute and when time goes by the file keeps growing and growing. A problem is when I need 500 observations from the data, I need to import the whole .csv file and that is a problem yes. Especially when I need to access the data fast.

In Python I use the data mostly in a data frame or panel.

Comment: What about using a database like MySQL/PostgreSQL/...

Comment: You might want to check out the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I thought about it but would you use tables? And is it possible to retrieve only the last xxx observations?

Comment: @ZachGates Can you be a little more specific? Store the data in dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to use DB, it is much more convenient to update tables in DB than a csv file, moreover if you have a substantial amount of observations, you will be able to access/manipulate your data much more faster.

Another solution is to keep separate updates in separate .csv files.
You can still keep your major file (the one which is regularly updated), and at the same time create separate files for each update.

Comment: Is there a Python friendly 'provider' you recommend for a DB?

Comment: Try to have a look at SQL Alchemy (it allows to abstract the code away from the underlying DB, and on top it offers Core and ORM modes). Another solution would be to use a python driver for a particular DB, you have just google for it.

Comment: +1 for the separate smaller CSV files. I don't know why this is not explored more often in time series data, the time is literally the hash reference that points to the file in the file system and loading is like ms. SUPER FAST! Much faster than load and unload of a database (am I wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

You maybe wanna check **RethinkDB**, it gives you fastness, reliability and also flexible searching ability, it has a good python driver. I also recommend to use **docker**, because in that case, regardless of which database you want to use, you can **easily store the data of your db inside a folder**, and you can anytime change that folder(when you have a 1TB hard, now you want to change it to 4TB hard). maybe using docker in your project is more important than DB.

Answer (score 0):

This was also my problem in 2017 and I struggled with the performance of relational databases. Switching to Redis was 20x faster, although very difficult to implement. To make things easier for myself and others, I wrote an open-source ORM for Python applications on Redis.

```
import popoto

# DEFINE YOUR MODEL
class AssetPrice(popoto.Model):
    asset = popoto.KeyField()
    timestamp = popoto.SortedField(type=datetime, sort_by=('asset',))
    close_price = popoto.FloatField()


# ADD DATA AS IT STREAMS IN
AssetPrice.create(asset="Bitcoin", timestamp=datetime(2022,1,1,12,0,0), close_price=47686.81)


# QUERY BY ASSET AND TIMESTAMP RANGE
AssetPrice.query.filter(
    asset="Bitcoin", 
    timestamp__gte=datetime(2022,1,1), timestamp__lt=datetime(2022,1,2),
    values=('close_price',)
)

>>> [{'close_price': 47686.81}, ..]
```

it's available as an easy pip install:

`pip install popoto`

Documentation here: https://popoto.readthedocs.io

Popoto is free and open source, so feel free to copy it and customize for your own needs